# Unable to connect to server PostgreSQL database with pgAdmin

Tags: postgresql, debian, pgadmin

I have a brand new `Debian 10` and `PostgreSQL` installation on a remote server and I want to connect with `pgAdmin` to this database from my PC. When I create a server on `pgAdmin` I have (I hide my host) :

> Unable to connect to server:
> could not connect to server: Connection timed out (0x0000274C/10060)
> Is the server running on host "...." and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

In the server installations seems ok, `PostgreSQL` status is active. When I run

```
netstat -nlp | grep 5432
```

I get

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5432            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      4014/postgres
tcp6       0      0 :::5432                 :::*                    LISTEN      4014/postgres
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     48416    4014/postgres        /var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432
```

And my PostgreSQL configuration is :

```
pg_hba.conf


#IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    all             all             all                     md5

#IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
host    all             all             all                     md5


postgresql.conf

listen_addresses = '*'
```

I restart postgresql service after with `sudo service postgresql restart`. In this example I add all hosts, I know it's not a secure way, but it's still a test, I will filter by Ip addresses after.

How to connect to a remote database in a local machine ?

Is there any additional configuration with `nftables` firewall to set up ?

Comment: So `pgAdmin` is on one machine and the `Postgres` server is on another, correct? If so then yes you need to verify if there is a firewall active between the two and if so let port `5432` through. You also need to check the setting for `listen_addresses` in `postgresql.conf`. By default it is set to `localhost`, which means it will not be listening to external interfaces. For more information see here [Listen addresses](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/runtime-config-connection.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-CONNECTION-SETTINGS)

Comment: That's it, database is on a remote server and pgAdmin is on a local PC. postgresql.conf seems ok, do you recommend a configuration in pg_hba.conf ? I will check firewall configuration also.

Comment: I check `postgresql.conf` and `pg_hba.conf` and everything seems ok. Port is open and even without any firewall configuration I can't connect to this remote database. Am I missing something important ?

Comment: The three reasons you get this error: 1) The server is not running 2) It is running, but not listening on that port at that address 3) It is running and listening on the port but the port is blocked.  So is the firewall open for port `5432`? Can you connect to the server locally from a shell on the remote server?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Configuration was fine : server is running, port is open, PostgreSQL configuration is correctly set. It's more deceitful : there is a global firewall on the network I use, it overpass everything. If I'm using an other network it's ok.